# JQuery How do I select EXACTLY the Text I need from dropdown options?

Tags: jquery

`:contains` just isnt doing it for me here. Its too coarse. and I cant seem to figure out the right way to get it.

(.js fiddle below)

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_button').click(function() {
        var cookieVal = "ab"; //This is what I want to find
        var select = "combo0";

        var optionThatMatchesCookie = $("#" + select + " option:contains('" + cookieVal + "')").val();
        alert(optionThatMatchesCookie); //returns the wrong entry! (returns 'cabd' not 'ab')

        if (typeof(optionThatMatchesCookie) != "undefined") {
            //now put that in the combobox
            $('#' + select).val(optionThatMatchesCookie);
        }
    });
});

<select class="inputfield" id="combo0" name="jobType">
    <option selected="selected">-select-</option>
    <option id="1">sssssssssss</option>
    <option id="18">fffffffffff</option>
    <option id="47">cabd</option>
    <option id="3">LPN/LVN</option>
    <option id="22">bbbbb</option>
    <option id="17">hhhhhhhhhh</option>
    <option id="15">aaaaaaa</option>
    <option id="16">zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz</option>
    <option id="5">ab</option>
    <option id="44">YYYYYYYYY</option>
    <option id="19">XXXXXX</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="my_button" value="test me"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KGabbert/mCDer/3/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It returns the `cabd` option because that contains "ab", and that's exactly what `:contains` is used for. If you're wanting to return the value of the `option` that exactly matches, you could use [`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
var optionThatMatchesCookie = $("#" + select + " option").filter(function() {
     return $(this).val() === cookieVal;  
}).val();
```

Here's a [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/hZ2kK/).

As an aside, note that [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special/typeof) is an operator, not a method, so you shouldn't put the operand in parentheses:

```
typeof optionThatMatchesCookie
```

Also note that you could shorten your code significantly to just this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_button').click(function() {
        var cookieVal = "ab",
            select = "combo0";
        $("#" + select).val(cookieVal); 
    });
});
```

If `cookieVal` does not match the value of one of the `option` elements then the value will not change. See another [working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/hZ2kK/1/).

Comment: Looks like you meant `.val()`, not `.text()`

Comment: @Eric - Which part are you talking about? I meant `.text()` not `.val()` at the very end of the first code snippet (now changed), but not sure where I meant `.val()` instead of `.text()`.

Comment: @Eric - Sorry, just re-read my answer and realised what you meant. I confused myself. Thanks!

Comment: you get the win for: $("#" + select).val(cookieVal);  I see now that I was thinking way to hard about this..

Comment: @KevinDeus - Always the way :) It took me a while to realise it was that simple, after writing out the rest of the answer! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to return matches of cookieVal:

```
    var optionThatMatchesCookie = $("#" + select + " value=['" + cookieVal +"']").val()
```

Answer (score 0):

It's normally better practice not to build selectors on the fly:

```
$(function() {
    $('#my_button').click(function() {
        var cookieVal = "ab"; //This is what I want to find
        var select = $("#combo0"); //Select the combo here

        var optionThatMatchesCookie = select.find("option").filter(function() {
            return $(this).text() === cookieVal; 
        }).text();
        alert(optionThatMatchesCookie); //returns the wrong entry! (returns 'cabd' not 'ab')

        if (typeof(optionThatMatchesCookie) != "undefined") {
            //now put that in the combobox
            select.val(optionThatMatchesCookie);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found this:

```
var optionThatMatchesCookie = $('#' + select).children('option[text="' + cookie + '"]').val();
```

which is better, this or the .filter() answer?